# Div height not resizing when height is given as %, but will when given as number in firefox

Tags: css

My problem is that I have one div nested inside another large div. The larger div is called content, and the smaller one is content-middle. The content div is the first (and only) element inside the  tag, and is properly resizing. The CSS is as follows:

```
body, html
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#003A69;
}

#content {
    width:100%;    
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#00693E;
    background: url(images/background-green.jpg) repeat;
}

#content-middle{
    background-color: white;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:930px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    color:black;
}
```

The HTML structure is like this: body->content->content-middle

The problem is that in Firefox, the div content-middle does not resize to the size of its container (100%) even if i put in something like 10000%. However, if I were to put a number in for min-height (such as 10000) it resizes properly.

This works properly in Opera, IE doesn't work (not surprising), havn't tried anything else. Is this a bug? Can anyone figure out a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change #content to 'height' instead of 'min-height'.

Comment: The problem with that is that if #content-middle has more content then then height of the window, #content won't expand to fit it, instead #content stays the same. Thats why I used min-height, so that it could (in theory) expand when needed. However, the min-height property does not seem to want to work with percentages.

Comment: If your `min-height` is 100% your `height` is 100%. There's no `>` or `< min-height ` when you want 100% so remove min-height.